# How do I merge objects with the same character within a column?

Tags: r

Let's say I have a DF of just 1 column "Genre"
and within that Genre there are "Horror", "Romance", "Fiction" etc.

**Genre**

`Horror
Horror
Romance
Fiction
Romance`

How do I code so that I can combine the "Horror" objects to just one?
So basically, I want the table to show

**Genre**

`Horror
Romance
Fiction`

Thanks in advance

Comment: `unique(DF$Genre)`

Comment: Let me revise my question sorry about that 
Let's say I have a DF of just 2 columns "Genre" and "score" within that Genre there are "Horror", "Romance", "Fiction" etc.



`Genre  Score
Horror   4
Horror   6
Romance  7
Fiction  3
Romance  10`

How do I code so that I can combine the "Horror" objects to just one? So basically, I want the table to show

`Genre  Score
Horror  mean(score)
Romance mean(score)
Fiction mean(score) `

Answer (score 0):

`unique(DF$Genre)`

or

```
DF %>%
distinct(Genre)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. If it doesnt trouble you, I want to know how I can make a summary of 2 columns genre and score. For example, "summarise(distinct(genre),mean(score))" doesn't work. The original DF contains the column genre,score.

Comment: the distinct function in fact deletes the rest of the column (score)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the table that you are looking for using the `aggregate` function.

```
## Your sample data
DF = read.table(text="Genre Score 
Horror 4 
Horror 6
Romance 7 
Fiction 3 
Romance 10", 
header = TRUE)
```

### Make the table

```
TAB = aggregate(DF$Score, list(DF$Genre), mean)
names(TAB) = c("Genre", "MeanScore")
TAB
    Genre MeanScore
1 Fiction       3.0
2  Horror       5.0
3 Romance       8.5
```

Comment: thank you so much. is there a way to change group.1 and x to another variable?